# How to install php rpm from remi's repo on RHEL 8 from ks.cfg file kickstart

Tags: php, rhel8

How to install php rpm from remi's repo on RHEL 8 from `ks.cfg` file kickstart ?

i tried with the file above but it failed with error during installation process

```
#version=RHEL8
bootloader --location=mbr --append="rhgb quiet crashkernel=auto"
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart

# Use graphical install
graphical

# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom

# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=fr-oss --xlayouts='fr (oss)'

# System language
lang fr_FR.UTF-8

# Network information
network --device=link --onboot=yes --hostname=computer --bootproto=static --ip=192.168.1.151 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --activate

# Add local Repositories
repo --name="BaseOS" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/BaseOS
repo --name="AppStream" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/AppStream
repo --name="Ansible29" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Ansible29
repo --name="Yarn" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Yarn
repo --name="Epel" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Epel
repo --name="Remi" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Remi

# Root password
rootpw $1$Hvsdfsdf1tXYdfdsfsdfsfec$qtWxFDzzBsfdfdfs2Xxnn.rfwZzX0 --iscrypted
# administrateur user
user --name=administrateur --iscrypted --password=$1$Hv1tXYec$qtfdgdfWxFDzzB2dsdfdgdXxnn.rfwZzX0

auth --passalgo=sha512 --useshadow

# X Window System configuration information
xconfig  --startxonboot

# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --disable

%pre --interpreter=/usr/bin/bash --log=/var/log/pre-installation-anaconda.log
%end

# Reboot auto after install
reboot

# SeLinux activation
selinux --disabled

# Intended system purpose
syspurpose --sla="Premium" --usage="Production"

# System timezone
timezone Europe/Paris --isUtc --nontp


module --name=php --stream=7.2 --disable
module --name=php --stream=remi-7.2

%packages --excludedocs
@^minimal-environment
@base-x
@GNOME
php
%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --disable
%end

%post --interpreter=/usr/bin/bash --log=/var/log/post-installation-anaconda.log
%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsxSz.png)

But in anaconda group or module php:remi-7.2 not found :§

it not depends about rhel version nether than php version

maybe i missed something else

Comment: Don't know what is the content of /run/install/repo/Remi ?  But for modules, you need "remi-modular" and "remi-safe" (like you need BaseOS and AppStream for distribution)

Comment: I found the solution you are right i need symply use modular repo of EPEL and not standard

Answer (score 0):

voici ma solution final

```
#version=RHEL8
bootloader --location=mbr --append="rhgb quiet crashkernel=auto"
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart

# Use graphical install
graphical

# Use CDROM installation media
cdrom

# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=fr-oss --xlayouts='fr (oss)'

# System language
lang fr_FR.UTF-8

# Network information
network --device=link --onboot=yes --hostname=toto--bootproto=static --ip=192.168.1.151 --netmask=255.255.255.0 --activate

# Add local Repositories
repo --name="BaseOS" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/BaseOS
repo --name="AppStream" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/AppStream
repo --name="Ansible29" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Ansible29
repo --name="Yarn" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Yarn
repo --name="RemiModular" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/RemiModular
repo --name="RemiSafe" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/RemiSafe
repo --name="Epel" --baseurl=file:///run/install/repo/Epel

# Root password
rootpw $dddd--iscrypted
# administrateur user
user --name=administrateur --iscrypted --password=$ddddddd

auth --passalgo=sha512 --useshadow

# X Window System configuration information
xconfig  --startxonboot

# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --disable

%pre --interpreter=/usr/bin/bash --log=/var/log/pre-installation-anaconda.log
%end

# Reboot auto after install
reboot

# SeLinux activation
selinux --disabled

# Intended system purpose
syspurpose --sla="Premium" --usage="Production"

# System timezone
timezone Europe/Paris --isUtc --nontp

%packages
@^minimal-environment
@base-x
@GNOME
@php:remi-7.2/common
@composer:2/common
@postgresql:12/server
%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --disable
%end

%post --interpreter=/usr/bin/bash --log=/var/log/post-installation-anaconda.log
%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end
```